# Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab, : 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'

Tags: r, plot, error-handling, curve

I wanted to plot the following piece wise function however I keep getting the error

```
a <- function(x) {ifelse(( x < -1), 0, ifelse((-1 < x & x < 2),(x^3 + 1)/9, ifelse((x > 2), 1, NA))) } 
 plot(a, xlim=c(-5, 5), ylim = c(-4, 7), col = "red") 
 abline(v = 0, h = 0)
```

Comment: Did you mean `x <=1`? Or `x < -1`? You are likely getting this error because `<-` has a meaning in R as the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly correct, but adding spaces to make it readable will help. The error is triggered as @Phil mentions because `x<-1` is interpreted by R as "assign the value of 1 to x." You are using the version of the plot command for plotting functions which is documented with the `curve` function (see `?curve`). You should probably include the `from=` and `to=` arguments, but the function will use the xlim values without them:

```
a <- function(x){ ifelse(( x < -1), 0, ifelse((-1 < x & x < 2),(x^3 + 1)/9, ifelse((x > 2), 1, NA))) }
plot(a, from=-5, to=5, n=201, xlim=c(-5, 5), ylim = c(-4, 7), col = "red")
abline(v = 0, h = 0, lty=3)
```

Note the addition to your `plot()` command. I changed the `abline` to use a dotted line which makes the function easier to see. Adding `n=201` increases the number of points in the line so the curve is smoother and the gap between the segments is smaller.

[image: Plot]